# "ipv6_cidr_block": all of `ipv6_cidr_block,ipv6_ipam_pool_id` must be specified

Tags: terraform

**Usage**: import

**Version**:
Terraform v1.1.9

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.11.0

I've something like this defined:

```
  assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = "true"
  cidr_block                       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames             = "true"
  enable_dns_support               = "true"
  instance_tenancy                 = "default"
  ipv6_cidr_block                      = "2600:0c00:eaa:a$$$::/56"
  ipv6_cidr_block_network_border_group = "$region"
  # ipv6_netmask_length                  = "56"
```

But keep getting:

```
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with aws_vpc.$vpc_Name,
│   on main.tf line 7, in resource "aws_vpc" "$vpc_Name":
│    7:   ipv6_cidr_block                      = "2600:0c00:eaa:a$$$::/56"
│ 
│ "ipv6_cidr_block": all of `ipv6_cidr_block,ipv6_ipam_pool_id` must be specified
```

I've seen this:

**ipv6_cidr_block** - can be set explicitly or derived from IPAM using ipv6_netmask_length.

**ipv6_ipam_pool_id** - conflicts with assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block.

**ipv6_netmask_length** - conflicts with ipv6_cidr_block. This can be omitted if IPAM pool as a allocation_default_netmask_length set.

IPAM is not defined for the account:

```
aws ec2 describe-ipam-pools
- IpamPools: []
```

And this happens whether "ipv6_netmask_length" is set or not.

Please, what am I doing wrong and how do I set it right?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states:

> "ipv6_cidr_block": all of `ipv6_cidr_block,ipv6_ipam_pool_id` must be specified

Both `ipv6_cidr_block` and `ipv6_ipam_pool_id` must be *specified*. This doesn't necessarily mean they need to have a value, so in your case, you should be fine to just leave it empty:

```
ipv6_cidr_block   = "2600:0c00:eaa:a$$$::/56"
ipv6_ipam_pool_id = ""
```

Comment: I know it is late, but etiquette dictates that I must say **"thank you"** despite the time. Thanks and have a great year.